# Make a callback for a service

Tags: android, service, in-app-billing

Im using this tutorial here [Tut](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/) to have inApp purchasing.  My problem is I cant seem to figure out how to call a function in my main activity once the service is connected.  Im trying to check if i need to restoreTransactions once the service is connected.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this would be to create a **BroadcastReceiver** in your activity and have the service use sendBroadcast with a custom intent. Data can be transmitted by using the Intent's putExtra() method. Make sure you register the receiver in the activity's onResume() and unregister it in onPause().

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed has a FAIL design:

```
public class BillingService extends Service implements ServiceConnection {

  ... ...

  @Override
  public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    ... ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    ... ...
  }

}
```

Ahhhh, looks like the blogger is trying to do some code re-factoring which he thought would be smarter by moving ServiceConnection out from Activity and implement it along with Service implementation. This is definitely a valid code re-factoring but a FAIL design as it loss the benefit and convenience of IPC (Inter-Process Communication) between Activity and Service. When talking about code re-factoring from OOP perspective, think more from the problem abstraction level not just rudely strip inner class off from the code level.

You should follow the correct design pattern from the [official dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Binder), define and implement ServiceConnection as a inner class of Activity, you will regain the benefit and convenience of IPC, simply call whatever method you defined in that Activity in onServiceConnected callback, once the service is up and ready:

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {

  ... ...

  /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
  private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
      ... ...
      // call a function in my main activity once the service is connected:
      this.foo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
      ... ...
    }
  };

}
```

Note that the way official dev guide suggested to do things is always the most reasonable and efficient. Android developer doesn't write the official dev guide only for fun. Hope this helps.

Comment: He actually is using the way the official guide says to do inapp billing with the billingservice, it seems a little different, but following what they did, they did the same thing

Comment: As I said, The code in the tutorial is definitely valid, and you can still achieve what you want by doing some extra jobs (i.e. pass Activity context as a reference to Service then call method on it). The point here is how to do thing more reasonable and efficient based on different use cases. In you situation, this kind of FAIL code refactoring doesn't help you gain any benefit other than adding coding complexity for solving your problem. I had done similar things before but finally realize the way Google suggested is always most reasonable and efficient, at least in most of common use cases.